# How do I query for the size of the newest island in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I would like to query for the size of the last island in a 'gaps and islands' problem in SQL Server (Azure).

Say I have the following table:

```
ID date status
500 2019-05-15 1 
528 2019-05-16 0 
538 2019-05-17 0 
550 2019-05-18 1 
580 2019-05-19 0 
590 2019-05-20 0
```

ID is an identity column
date is a date column
status is 0 or 1.

I want to find out how many days that a status has been set to 0. In this case today is 2019-05-20.

How do I write a query to pull the count of the last status columns being 0 (ie 2)?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by how many days? Should status groups that end with a 1 (chronologically) be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the most recent record with `status = 1` and use it to count the recent rows with `status = 0`.

```
select
    count(*) as cnt
from yourTable
where [date] > (select max([date]) from yourTable where [status] = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to count rows (rather than use date arithmetic), then a safe method is:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from t
where [date] > all (select [date] from t where status = 1);
```

This should work even when there are no `1`s.